# How to use/call amazon connect API StartChatContact & StartContactChat to initiate the chat channel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, chat, amazon-connect

I am trying to follow [StartContactChat](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_StartChatContact.html) & [CreateParticipantConnection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect-participant/latest/APIReference/API_CreateParticipantConnection.html) to initiate the chat from third party applications e.g. Postman.
i want to route the chat to agent on talk to agent message from API, the chat should be routed to the agent in amazon connect.
`StartChatContact's Request Syntax` is given like this:

```
PUT /contact/chat HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/json

{
   "Attributes": { 
      "string" : "string" 
   },
   "ChatDurationInMinutes": number,
   "ClientToken": "string",
   "ContactFlowId": "string",
   "InitialMessage": { 
      "Content": "string",
      "ContentType": "string"
   },
   "InstanceId": "string",
   "ParticipantDetails": { 
      "DisplayName": "string"
   }
}
```

I have done with it using URL: PUT `https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/contact/chat` and got the `ParticipantToken` and now trying to create the participant connect using `CreateParticipantConnection` - `https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/participant/connection`  but keep facing the error:

```
{
    "message": "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized"
}
```

i have added the participant token generated by `StartContactChat` in `Authorization --> AWS Signature --> Session Token` as well as in `Header` but still the still getting the AccessDeniedExcetion.

Answer (score 1):

The CreateParticipantConnection API does not belong to the same service as the StartChatContact API. As a result, `https://connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/participant/connection` is the wrong endpoint for the latter API. Instead, it should be `https://participant.connect.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/participant/connection`